# If there were no space between nuclei, how big would the Earth be?

Tags: earth, estimation, neutron-stars, scales

I have some people telling me it would be the size of baseball. I am quite doubtful on this. If this is true, then the gaps must be so incredibly huge that everything should be transparent. I am not a physics student, just wondering.

Comment: @coffee We aren't a discussion site. We have quite a few rules on which types of questions we allow (see [about], [help/on-topic], and [ask]). It's OK to raise doubt about the suitability of the question for the site, as long as it is done constructively.

Comment: What experimental evidence do you know of coffee, that says there is no space between nuclei ?    Without that, your question is not about Physics.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of assuming the earth is made of metallic hydrogen, let's just compare Earth's density of $5.52 \times 10^3 kg/m^3$ to that of neutrons' $2.3 \times 10^{17} kg/m^3$ because degenerate matter consisting of neutrons is what you get when electrons are forced into nuclei. That's a density increase of about $4.17 \times 10^{13}$ (at least 3 orders of magnitude different from Pranav's proton-atom volume ratio estimate), or a radial decrease of about $3.47 \times 10^4$.

This puts a neutron Earth radius at 184 metres or a huge baseball STADIUM including car park.

Comment: That's roughly what I got.

Comment: I guess you just put into the context up to the density of neutron, and start making earth density to the same and then calculated the volume.... Does that mean, neutron is the mostly packed in the universe (that is without any empty spaces)
I liked the way you calculated though.

Comment: Good question. In fact neutrons themselves are pretty spacious... Because neutrons, like protons , aren't fundamental particles but made of quarks and gluons. but to compress neutrons to get rid of this space requires so much force...the neutron degeneracy pressure, and the result is usually a black hole.

Answer (score 7):

When you look at crystalline substances, there is really not that much space between the atoms. What people mean when they say that an atom is mostly empty space, is that the INSIDE of the atom is very sparsely populated with *stuff*.

This is because the *stuff* in question, the nucleus and the electrons, are tiny in comparison to the actual *size of the atom*. The nucleus is typically a few hundred thousandths of an angstrom unit, or $\approx 10^{-15} \text{meters}$ in diameter. The entire atom, on the other hand, has a diameter to the order of an angstrom, or $10^5$ times larger than the nucleus. The electrons are even tinier, so much so that the *volume* that each electron occupies is negligible in comparison to the nucleus.

A simple calculation will tell you that the volume occupied by an atom is $\approx 10^{15}$ times the volume of its building blocks, for the Hydrogen atom.

A similar calculation for an atom of a heavier element would tell you $V_{atom} \approx 10^{10} \times V_{nucleus}$

If you applied this reduction, by removing all that *empty* volume inside the atom, to the Earth, you would get an

$$
V_{earth}'=V_{earth} \times 10^{-12} \\
d_{earth}' = d_{earth} \times 10^{-4} = 1300 \text{m}
$$

P.S.: The empty space isn't really *empty* space. The currently accepted model of the atom says that an electron can be anywhere inside that space, but has a higher probability of being in a particular part of it. As David pointed out, it is more accurate to say **"Increasing the density of the earth to the density of the nucleus, while keeping the mass the same."**

Comment: A little nitpick: I don't like talking about it as "removing empty volume" because as you pointed out earlier, it really isn't empty space. One more accurate way would be to just talk about the size of a sphere with the Earth's mass but the density of an atomic nucleus.

Comment: Damn, I thought I had put in a little footnote about that. I'm going to add it right away

Comment: I don't understand the $10^{-12}$ factor - you're scaling the linear dimensions by a volume scale factor, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please check your calculations. Your answer is in microns when the Schwarzschild radius of the earth is 9mm.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the Earth could be compressed and turned into a neutron star. Neutron stars have overall densities up to $5.9\times 10^{17}\,\text{kg/m}^3$ ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star)). Since the total mass of the Earth is about $5.9\times 10^{24}\,\text{kg}$, it would be a sphere with a volume of about $10^7\,\text{m}^3$, which corresponds with a radius of about $134\,\text{m}$.

Answer (score 0):

earth volume is about $1,083,206,916,846$ cubic kilometers. The hydrogen atom is about $99.9999999999996\%$ empty. Based on this, if you take the empty space out of earth it becomes as big as a swimming pool of $1000\times 100 \times 1$ meters.

Answer (score -2):

0.8768 femtometers. the same size as a proton.

Comment: The [Pauli Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) is  what prevents your answer from being correct.

Comment: Actually even the Earth's Schwarzschild radius is bigger than this.